# Why is model automatically passed to partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I created a new ASP.NET MVC project (.net framework 4.5.2) and edited HomeController.cs file:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Test { get; set; }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Contact()
  {
    MyModel model = new MyModel()
    {
      Id = 34,
      Test = "Foo"
    };
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

Contact.cshtml view:

```
@model WebApplication6.Controllers.MyModel
@Html.Partial("_Partial1")
```

And _Partial1.cshtml file:

[image]

The model is automatically passed to partial view, without explicitly adding it like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_Partial1", model)
```

I can't find documentation on this behaviour. How can I prevent that model is passed to partial view. The behaviour isn't critical ofcourse, but I found that some developers used Model properties in partial views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass model to a view in your GET method, a [ViewDataDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx) is created and its `Model` property is set to the value of your model (in your case `MyModel`) which in turn is assigned to the `HtmlHelper.ViewData` property.

By default, when you do not specify a model when using `@Html.Partial()`, the current `ViewDataDictionary` is passed to the partial (refer the [source code for PartialExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/PartialExtensions.cs) which in turn calls the `RenderPartialInternal` of [HtmlHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs))

If you want to pass a `null` model, then you need to use the overload which passes a new `ViewDataDictionary`

```
@Html.Partial("_Partial1", new ViewDataDictionary())
```

or if you want to pass a different model

```
@Html.Partial("_Partial1", new AnotherModel())
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("_Partial1", Model.SomeProperty)
```

Note that in the last case, if `SomeProperty` is `null`, then the model in the view will be passed to the partial.